# How to prevent the sidenav of angular material from being completely hidden

Tags: angular

I have the following sidenav in my project based on the component "sidenav" of angular material.

```
<button class="btn-toggle" mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle();iconoToggle=!iconoToggle">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="iconoToggle">chevron_left</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="!iconoToggle">chevron_right</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-sidenav-container>
                <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'" [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56" opened>

                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <!-- Sidebar -->
                        <nav id="sidebar">
                            <div class="sidebar-header">
                                <img src="assets/images/img_p.png" />
                                <p>Lucia Pérez</p>
                                <p>IPS Admin</p>
                            </div>

                            <ul class="menu-final">
                                <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Ayuda y Soporte</li>
                                <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Cerrar Sesión</li>
                                <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Terminos Legales</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </mat-sidenav>
                <mat-sidenav-content>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    <zonasegura-footer></zonasegura-footer>
                </mat-sidenav-content>
```

The above code would look like this:

[Example One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r55c.png)

It is a simple component, it has a functionality in responsive based on the example responsive that provides angular material.

The button tag is in charge of hiding and showing the sidenav, as shown in this example [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/poklklombbp)

¿It is possible to achieve that when I click the button that hides the sidenav, it does not hide completely, if there is not a part of the content outside?

And what I mean by that is the following, not to be completely hidden but to leave a visible part:

[Example Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn9dV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the forked StackBlitz for a possible solution to your problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qjmrq

Essentially, we're offsetting both containers 30px to the right:

SCSS:

```
.example-container {
  --visible-drawer-space: 70px;
}

// --8<-- //

::ng-deep {
  .mat-drawer {
    &.mat-drawer-side {
      transform: translate3d(calc(-100% + var(--visible-drawer-space)), 0, 0);
      visibility: visible !important; // always visible
    }
  }

  .mat-drawer-content {
    margin-left: var(--visible-drawer-space);
  }
}
```